# Find all lineary dependent subsets of vectors

Tags: math, vector, linear-algebra

I have vectors in such form

```
(1 1 1 0 1 0)
(0 0 1 0 0 0)
(1 0 0 0 0 0) 
(0 0 0 1 0 0) 
(1 1 0 0 1 0) 
(0 0 1 1 0 0) 
(1 0 1 1 0 0)
```

I need to find all linear dependent subsets over Z2.

For example 1,2,5 and 3,6,7.

Comment: And what have you tried? Also, homeworks should be tagged so.

Comment: @Boris Stitnicky, I thought about brute force, but hope there something better. Gauss elimination may not help because of i need all.

Comment: Gee this is such a standard task... and I am so dumb today...

Comment: @Boris Stitnicky, give me hint please, what i should read?

Comment: Got it, they call it dynamic programming, IINM. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Answer (score 0):

OK, my 5 cents, brute force, IINM, is iterating over all subsets of the set of vectors. So, instead, you go from the bottom, where singleton sets of each vectors are obviously linearly independent.

In the next step, for each singleton set, you make a list by trying to add each of the remaining vectors in the set, and see which of such pairs are independent, taking note of those pairs, you've already tested, to prevent repetitive effort.

In the 3rd step, for each independent pair, you'll try to add each one of the remaining vectors to make triples, you test the new vector for independence, and mark the triples you've already tested.

This should provide much saving over brute force, with the worst case being a set of all independent vectors.